# Best way to clean tiles (shower)

Tags: walls, shower, tile, floor, cleaning

What's the best way to clean tiles? Especially in the part between the tiles (which the glue I suppose)?
Is there any good trick/recipe?
Shower tiles in case it matters.

Comment: The material between the tiles is called "grout".   Are you trying to clean some problem in particular?  General cleanup?  built up soap scum?   mineral deposits?  mildew?

Comment: @DaveM:Yes build up soap and  general cleanup

Answer (score 2):

As commented, the material is grout, and the spaces are grout-lines.

There are "grout brushes" for sale with a particular focus on helping to clean that area by having narrow lines of bristles that will get in there effectively.

Comment: So it is only a matter of brush? Not of material to use as a cleaner?

Comment: If you have soap scum or hard water, use a product for that ie CLR, soap scrum remover, etc. If you have mold or mildew, bleach. The brush will help scratch the surface of the grout to deep clean. But be careful, if you brush to hard and remove grout, then you will need to reseal the grout. You could also use vinegar in a spray bottle to remove calcium buildup.

Comment: You need to be careful with acid cleaners - they can keep right on going when they have dissolved any calcium build-up and attack the grout - they also don't help any and can still attack the grout if your problem is **not** calcium build-up. A grout brush will help get mechanical action and your cleaner of choice applied to the problem area. What cleaner works best on your particular build-up is going to depend on local conditions - and slides a bit near product recommendations, which are off-topic. If it's just built-up soap, you may not need any. A powder or gel product for "scrubbing" next

Comment: The tiles color is black. Won't bleach ruin the color?

Comment: Of the tile? not likely at all. The color is literally baked-in to tiles. try bleaching a brown or green glass beer bottle - it won't turn clear.